# Android: Is It Possible To Set drawableLeft Outsite The TextViews 9patch Background?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set drawableLeft outsite the TextViews 9patch background?

i'm using this code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_9patch"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImg"
        android:text="Hello World" />
```

and I want that android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImg" will be at the left of the android:background="@drawable/background_9patch" .

1. Can I do it with a single TextView or should i use  TextView + ImageView in a LinearLayout ?
2. Can I set the size of the drawable in: drawableLeft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your background is a custom 9-patch, you could just modify the background image to have a fixed-size transparent section on the left side of the stretchable content, which provides enough padding for the left `Drawable`.  This is how the framework creates backgrounds for widgets like `CheckBox` that shift the text to be beside the corresponding button.

Comment: Maybe I didn't got it - but my android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImg" is inside the strachable area of the 9patch (so if i'll add a transparent section on the left side - the drawable wont be in the new section - it will be in the strachable section).

Comment: Where your view content goes in relation to the 9-patch is defined by the content area bars (bottom and right side of the image...the top and left define the stretch zones), so that would only occur if you also excluded the transparent area with those bars.

Comment: How can i set the android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImg" size - only in the .png?

Comment: The content will be as big as the Drawable is, which by default is the intrinsic size of the image.  If you adjust the Drawable bounds or wrap it in something like a ScaleDrawable, you could change it.  You'd have to set the `drawableLeft` property in Java instead of XML in that case.  It's probably best to provide the asset at the correct size that you need if you can.